# Is there an equivalence between a graded vector space and its degree-shifted counterpart?

Tags: vector-space-isomorphism, graded-rings, graded-algebras

I am studying graded vector spaces and I have a simple question. Let me denote by $\mathbb Z_2=\mathbb Z\text{mod}2=\{-1,0,+1\}$. Now let's perform a shift by an integer $k$ and get the set $\mathbb Z_2+k=\mathbb Z\text{mod}2+k=\{k-1,k,k+1\}$.

Intuitively, I have the feeling that the two sets $\mathbb Z_2$ and $\mathbb Z_2+k$ are equivalent, in that a $\mathbb Z_2$-graded vector space has the same decomposition in vector subspaces as a $\mathbb (\mathbb Z_2+k)$-graded vector space. The only difference is the degrees of the homogeneous elements in each space, which are naturally shifted by $k$.

Is the $(\mathbb Z_2+k)$-graded vector space the same as the initial $\mathbb Z_2$-graded vector space?
If yes, is it because of some sort of isomorphism between the two sets $\mathbb Z_2$ and $\mathbb Z_2+k$?

Comment: Your definition of $\Bbb Z_2$ is wrong, it should be $\Bbb Z_2=\{0,1\}$. Moreover what is a $\Bbb Z_2+k$-graded vector space?

Comment: I was under the impression that by $\mathbb Z$ one means the set of all integers (positive and negative). Under this assumption, $\mathbb Z_2$ should contain -1, 0 and +1. No? As I wrote in the question, by $\mathbb Z_2+k$ graded vector space I mean the degree-shifted by $k$ $\mathbb Z_2$-graded vector space.

Comment: Yes, $\Bbb Z$ is the set of all integers. But $\Bbb Z_2$ is supposed to be the set of integers *up to multiples of 2*. As we can write $1=-1+2\cdot 1$ we find that both $-1$ and $1$ represent the same number in $\Bbb Z_2$.

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot for the clarification!